# VS2010 Code Analysis, any way to automatically fix certain warnings?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, code-analysis

I must say I really like the new code analysis with VS 2010, I have a lot of areas in my code where I am not using `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`and code analysis is warming me about this.

I am pretty sure I want to use `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`where ever code analysis has detected it is missing on Convert.ToString operations.

Is there anyway to get VS to automatically fix warnings of this type?

Comment: It seems dangerous to change program behavior with a global replace. (i.e. change from CurrentCulture to InvariantCulture)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do this in VS Code Analysis but [CodeIt.Right](http://submain.com/codeit.right) performs similar analysis (only on source code) and includes auto corrections with every rule. Give it a try!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do that with Visual Studio but [Resharper 5](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/whatsnew/index.html) has a **Structural Search and Replace** functionnality that could work for that.